# Is there any way to set CSS animation to work differently on e.g. button On / Off?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in a situation where I want to animate mobile navigation. User clicks on a burger and the nav slides down, by clicking on any link or the burger itself  nav slides back up.

Till this day I solved this by making 2 divs where first has
`display: block;` with animation to slide down and the another has `display: none;` with animation to slide up. After clicking on burger these two options would switch and that will do the thing.

It works just fine, however, I think it can be done with less code.

Comment: Use toggle buttons

Comment: Instead of using separate divs, you can create a single class with your animations and use JavaScript/jQuery/your choice of programming to toggle that class on burger or link click. So you would set your menu's CSS as if its slid up and off screen, and your animated class will include the sliding down animation. I can create a minimal representation if wanted

Comment: @Xenvi minimal representation would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

This uses the css `transition` property to animate the sliding.

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("menu-hidden");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-hidden {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Toggle menu</button>
<div class="menu" id="menu">Menu content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Make `click ()` event to assign **ON & OFF** value to button.

````
function onoff(){
  currentvalue = $('#onoff').val();
  if(currentvalue == "Off"){
    $('#onoff').val("On");
  }else{
    $('#onoff').val("Off")
  }
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="On" id="onoff" onclick="onoff();"> ```
````

Comment: Check @David Malášek

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution. May I ask is there a way to do it without jQuery?

Comment: There is always a way without jQuery http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method. This simply makes it so the menu is positioned out of the screen using transform translate, transitions and z-index, and on hamburger click it toggles the menu to slide down to its original position. I have also added functionality so that menu items, on click, will also toggle the menu slide.

```js
document.getElementById("hamburger").addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("slide");
});

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item")).forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("menu").classList.toggle("slide");
  });
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

#menu {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide {
  transform: translateY(0) !important;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button id="hamburger">Toggle</button>
</nav>
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Link 1</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Link 2</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Link 3</li>
</ul>
```